# why New prompts are not being effective after running in cognos?

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I have a report which is scheduled which has some prompt values. Now i modified the report by removing the existing prompt value and adding another prompt value.

But while I schedule it again and ran it, it throws output with the old prompt value.Please suggest.

Comment: Are you sure the schedule was running successfully? Did you check the run history? As default, Cognos display the last saved result.
If the last schedule run was failed, then it will display the old results (with previous prompt values).

Answer (score 0):

After scheduling your report, go to "My Activities and Schedules" on the Cognos Portal and look into "Past Activities" if your report has a Succeeded status. When a report schedule has a Failed status, it will throw output with the old Succeeded version. Probably your changes are creating an error into your report

Hope this is going to help.

Best regards,

T. M.